# How to manage click events in RecyclerView following ViewModel approach?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Can you please help me?
I've been trying to figure this out, what is the best approach to manage click events in RecyclerViews when using a ViewModel based design?

For now I'm just passing the ViewModel to the Adapter and then to the ViewHolder, is that ok? (maybe leaking memory, maybe bad practice)

I have other 2 options, the good old callback way with interfaces or just passing a LiveData to the ViewHolder (that LiveData is gonna be observed by the Fragment)

Answer (score 4):

I saw a very good approach on this from one of CodeLabs.

Outside the ListAdapter Class you create OnClickListener class that takes a lambda with the entity Class as the parameter.

```
//OnclickListener class outside the Adapter class but on the same file with the adapter

class OnClickListener(val clickListener: (asteroid: Asteroid) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(asteroid: Asteroid) = clickListener(asteroid)
}
```

The `Asteroid Class` is the entity, here you can switch with your entity class if you have one.

Inside the Listener class you define onClick function that is set to the lambda parameter.

The created Listener Class is then passed to the ListAdapter Class Constructor

```
class AsteroidListAdapter(private val clickListener: OnClickListener) : ListAdapter<Asteroid, AsteroidListAdapter.ViewHolder>(
        DiffClass()) {
```

Override `onBindViewHolder()` as follows

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val asteroid = getItem(position)

        //view.setOnClickListener
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

            clickListener.onClick(asteroid)
        }
        holder.bind(asteroid)
    }
```

Inside the  fragment's onCreateView you will need to set the RecyclerView's Adapter.

The code is shown on this image

[image]

Here we are setting the RecyclerView's adapter and passing the Listener to the Adapter's constructor.

You will see you have access to the clicked Entity and you can navigate to detail screen and the like.

I know this kinda tricky but you can [see step by step of this here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-interacting-with-items#3)

Comment: I'd make two changes on your solution: 1) instead of declaring OnClickListener as a class like that, just make it an interface; 2) instead of calling holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { ... } on onBindViewHolder, it's better to call ...setOnClickListener(this), make your adapter implement View.OnClickListener and implenent its onClick method; that way you don't create an anonymous object everytime you call onBindViewHolder. Other than that, that's a great way o f handling clicks in a RecyclerView.

Comment: Thank you so mucho for your answer, but I have a doubt, ViewModel is not supposed to take care of view events then?

Comment: Damn, that's a beautiful approach!

Comment: Like @cd1, I'd make it an interface and also I wouldn't make it to be required to create the adapter. I'd make a method to set the listener (with the possibility to set it to null) in the adapter class. When you create a View you're not required to provide a listener, right? You could set it only when you need it, same applies here.